# How do I close an Event-Handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I do have following situation (WPF; C#):

1) I initialize a camera and starting an event-handler which displays the live-image automatically in the background

2) Afterwards I would like to close this open event-handler again if for example the user clicks a button. 
Question: How can I do that?

My code:

```
private void InitCamera(int CamID)
{
    ...
    Camera.EventFrame += onFrameEventFocusCam;    // start event
    ...
}



private void onFrameEventFocusCam(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ...
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // Convert bitmap to WPF-Image
        var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap);
        var hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();

        System.Windows.Media.ImageSource wpfBitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
        hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        image_fokus.Source = wpfBitmap;
        image_fokus.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill;


        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
Camera.EventFrame -= onFrameEventFocusCam;
```

Comment: It did not work and I get following error message: "Thread was interrupted from a waiting state" and the code lines with "Dispatcher.Invoke" is highlighted.

Comment: You can try to check whether Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted before the Dispatcher.Invoke .... line, but its just a guess

Comment: I changed the code this way: 
After the line "Camera.EventFrame -= onFrameEventFocusCam;" I checked if "Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted" is started in a while-loop, but is NOT started.